# Filter by multiple columns with $_GET

Tags: php, html, mysql

Working on a website where you can add news, that data gets sent to a database and then converted to json, which is used in an app.

I'm having trouble with filtering the news using the url. I want to be able to filter news by 2 database columns, Type and Region. When I add the news I need to specify which type[can only choose 1] of news it is and in what region[can choose multiple] it goes under. Now when i'm in the app, let's say I want to only see "Emergency" news from "X" region. For that I would check "Emergency" type checkbox and "X" region checkbox.

With my current code I can filter the news by type perfectly, but im having trouble adding an extra filter to only show X region news.

```
<?php

function turnIntoUTF8($arrayName) {
if (is_array($arrayName)) {
    foreach ($arrayName as $k => $v) {
        $arrayName[$k] = turnIntoUTF8($v);
    }
} else if (is_string ($arrayName)) {
    return utf8_encode($arrayName);
}
    return $arrayName;
}

$tag = $_GET["tag"];//Tag = type
//Tried adding a new GET here.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(`tag`, '$tag')//Tried to do another FIND_IN_SET here with &&.
ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(turnIntoUTF8($emparray));
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

[image: The 2 columns:]

Currently I can use this url: http://localhost/vvuudised/getNewsJson.php?tag=uudis,teade to show only news that have their type set as "uudis" or "teade. The outcome is the following: [image]

Now if I wanted to I would filter the news to only show lets say "rohuneeme" region news with the url. How can I do that. Thanks and sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.